# Authentication Failure error for Baidu Cloud Push API

Tags: api, push-notification, notifications, baidu

I am using Baidu Push API to send push notification messages to my device. But I am getting Authentication failure in the response. I tried to contact Baidu support but they just don't reply.

**Error response:**
{
"request_id": 2727123347,
"error_code": 30603,
"error_msg": "Authentication Failed"
}

Following are my API params details

**----------POST Url----------**

https://api.tuisong.baidu.com/rest/3.0/push/all

**----------Headers----------**

```
Content-Type = application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8
User-Agent = BCCS_SDK/3.0 (Darwin; Darwin Kernel Version 14.0.0: Fri Sep 19 00:26:44 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2782.1.97~2/RELEASE_X86_64; x86_64) PHP/5.6.3 (Baidu Push Server SDK V3.0.0 and so on..) cli/Unknown ZEND/2.6.0
```

**----------Form Data----------**

```
apikey = XXXXXXXXXX
expires = 1593494000
msg = %7B%22title%22%3A%22hello%22%2C%22description%22%3A%22hello%20world%22%2C%22notification_builder_id%22%3A0%2C%22notification_basic_style%22%3A7%2C%22open_type%22%3A0%2C%22url%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.baidu.com%22%2C%22pkg_content%22%3A%22%22%2C%22custom_content%22%3A%7B%22key%22%3A%22value%22%7D%2C%22target_channel_id%22%3A%22%22%7D

timestamp = 1593493655
secret_key = XXXXXXXXXXX
sign = f7a7b96457162795c491d993a1b821a7
```

I have used below references for preparing params and making API call.

1. http://push.baidu.com/doc/restapi/restapi
2. http://push.baidu.com/doc/restapi/sdk_developer

Please help me to fix this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The Baidu Rest Api is very sensitive regarding the encoding of the signature string before you hash it. See http://push.baidu.com/doc/restapi/sdk_developer -> Signature algorithm section. You have to use the **exact** `UrlEncode()` algorithm.

Doing extensive trial and error I found the C# method `System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(raw)` which uses the encoding expected by the Rest API.
Make sure that the method you are using in the language of your choice encodes as follows:

raw: `{"Hello":"Stackoverflow @ https://stackoverflow.com"}`

encoded: `%7B%22Hello%22%3A%22Stackoverflow+%40+https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%22%7D`

Note:

- `' '` (space) encoded as `'+'` and **not** `%20`
- Hex values  (e-g. in `%7B`) use **capital letters**